# php file upload with mysql filename update

Tags: php, mysql, upload

I am trying to combined these two script (a file upload) and (a mysql update) so that the image file is both uploaded to the correct folder and the file path is then updated in the mysql database. I know the $sql update query is wrong and thats where my trouble is. Any help would be great.

```
//db connection
require "connect.db.php";

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }

// update data in mysql database
$sql="UPDATE `characters` SET ch_image='/upload/$_FILES["file"]["name"]' WHERE ID='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully updated.
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='test.html'>View result</a>";
touch('../file.html');
clearstatcache();
}

else {
echo "Whoops: " . mysql_error(); ;
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Where are you setting `$id`?  And what is the structure of your database?  Have you tried `echo`ing your query and running the query in something like phpMyAdmin to see if it produces an error message, or at least looked at `mysql_error()` after your `mysql_query()`?

Comment: I know the $sql string is wrong so it would just come back as a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `$sql` to this

```
$sql="UPDATE `characters` SET ch_image='/upload/" . $_FILES['file']['name'] . "' WHERE ID='$id'";
```

Comment: Clearly an error -- this is definitely a step in the right direction.  I fear there are more to come, however.

Comment: $id is missing, it will fail again

Comment: $id is set else where, each script works on its own. I am trying to merge them now

Comment: After fix I get the following "Invalid fileSuccessful
View result" In the sql database the following was entered into the ch_image filed "/upload/" the file was not uploaded to the folder

Comment: added `die;` after echo "invalid file"

Comment: next problem seems to be why a .jpg is getting flagged as an invalid file type?